# Is it safe to cast with getActivity()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm writing an app that has a parent `Activity` and several child `Fragments`.  I am trying to get the Fragment to communicate back to the parent Activity.  I know there are several ways to do this, including making an interface and implementing that in the parent Activity.  However, I am interested in this method:

```
ParentActivity activity = (ParentActivity) getActivity();
activity.someMethod();
```

This approach takes less code and is less complex.  However, is this cast safe to do in production code?  Or is an interface safer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this -

```
private ParentActivity callback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    //callback = (ParentActivity ) activity;
    // make sure there is no cast exception
    callback = (ParentActivty.class.isAssignableFrom(activity
            .getClass())) ? (ParentActivity) activity : null;

    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    callback = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

now when you do any method call , call it like this -

```
if(callback!=null)
{
callback.someMethod();
}
```

this method is safe .

Comment: Does this still work? (`onAttach(Activity activity)` has been marked as deprecated, leaving with only `onAttach(Context context)`)

Comment: It wont work with the deprecated onAttach method. The new one passes a Context, and although you could cast it as an Activity you'll find yourself back at square one. I'd recommend following Google's [new advice](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface) of using an interface defined in the Fragment and using the Activity's onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) method.

Answer (score 5):

It is safe (i.e. you won't get a `ClassCastException`), as long as you make sure that *only* `ParentActivity` ever creates/adds your Fragment.

These classes are now effectively [coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Disadvantages), which is, *in general*, not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

By casting to a specific Activity class (ParentActivity), you are losing the ability to re-use the fragment with different activities. It's safe to cast, as long as you only use the fragment with that one activity.

Using an interface allows the fragment to be used with multiple activities - you just need to implement the interface in the activities that use the fragment.

Another option is to use an Event Bus - like [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Answer (score 1):

It is safe if you know that the fragment won't be used in another activity. You can also do checks with `instanceof` so you can be sure that it will be the right type.
There are some possibilities where getActivity() might return null (when the fragment is not attached) so it's a good habit to check if the activity is null, or even better: `myFragment.isAdded()`. Otherwise you would get a NullPointerException when calling `activity.someMethod()`.

So the safe code would be:

```
if (isAdded() && getActivity() instanceof ParentActivity){
    ParentActivity activity = (ParentActivity) getActivity();
    activity.someMethod();
}
```

Of course there are some other approaches, like passing listeners to the fragments or using a shared eventbus like Guava or Otto, which also have their pros and cons. The easiest way is the one described above, and if you use it carefully (check against null, correct class) it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Directly [from the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface):

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

```
// HeadlinesFragment.java
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    public void setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
        mCallback = activity;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    // ...
}


// MainActivity.java
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof HeadlinesFragment) {
            HeadlinesFragment headlinesFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) fragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `ParentActivity` is derived from `Activity`.

`getActivity()` will provide you a pointer to the parent activity. So, there's no problem in the cast.

It is not "the Android way" to do things, but anyway, neither Google does lots of thing "the Android way" and this cast will surely continue to work ok in future Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, this not a good approach, google own documentation recommends using the interface, but if you choose to use this approach try something like:

```
Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);   

    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

to avoid the type `NullPointerException` error

```
if(this.mActivity != null){
       this.mActivity.someMethod();
}
```