# Is it safe to cast an Activity in a fragment to call a method from the parentActivity?

Tags: java, android

In my fragment I call a method from my parentActivity which has a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I read on some posts that casting an Activity can cause errors, but because I only have one parentActivity which manages all my fragments, I don't see why it would cause an error.

**Method call in fragment**

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSDCardAccess();
```

**Method in parentActivity**

```java
public void getSDCardAccess(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that your fragment will only be used by your mainActivity, I think there is no problem...

Comment: @diAz Ok thanks for clarifying. I was not sure because it seems that casting Activities is frowned upon in alot of posts.

Comment: However, it seems more interesting to use an interface if you plan to use your fragment with another activity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166370/7528285

Comment: It isn't recommended because it tightly couples your `Fragment` to your `Activity` - my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36360141/1219389) goes into more detail

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one `ParentActivity`that handles all the fragments in your application, it is possible to use the way you mentionned. But I would advice you to follow [Google recommended way](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface) of using interfaces to allow `Fragment` to communicate up to it's `Activity` or else these classes will be [coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Disadvantages).

If you decide to follow up your approach, please consider that `getActivity()` [may return null](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getactivity) if the `Fragment` is associated with a `Context`.